# sqlachemy core: how to do inner join and multiple joins

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Note this is for the core, not orm.

Hope some one can help me with these 2 questions :

1) There seems to be `outerjoin` and plain `join` but how does one do inner join?

2) What is the syntax to do multiple joins. I was able to do one join, but not sure the syntax for multiple joins.

My 1st join which works looks like this :

```
select([...]).select_from(outerjoin(a, b))
```

but it generates some errors for this syntax to do two joins :

```
select([...]).select_from(outerjoin(a, b).select_from(outerjoin(ma, tr))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

1. `join` does INNER JOIN by default. `outerjoin` calls `join` with argument `isouter=True`.

If our desired sql query is

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col2, c.col3
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.col1 = b.col1
LEFT JOIN c ON c.col1 = b.col2
```

Then the sqlalchemy-core statement should be:

```
select(
    [a.c.col1, b.c.col2, c.c.col3]
).select_from(
    a.outerjoin(
        b, a.c.col1 == b.c.col1
    ).outerjoin(
        c, b.c.col2 == c.c.col1
    )
)
```

- The `on clause` is not necessary if the relationship has been defined and is not ambiguous.
- The `outerjoin` functions can nested rather than chained (as you have done for the simple join), i.e.

  ```
  outerjoin(outerjoin(a, b), c)
  ```

  but I find that form less readable.